# Local vs distance function metric structures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

The geodesic distance $d(p_1, p_2)$ on a geodesically complete, Riemanian manifold is a metric in the sense of a metric space metric. I'd like to know when other infinitesimal metric structures (e.g. finlser metrics) induce such a global metric and what the exact relation of the two things is.

What is the largest class of Lagrangians $\mathcal{L}: TM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the action it assigns to its stationary curves defines a distance function in the sense of metric spaces.

I'm also interested in any procedure that recovers a local metric structure (i.e. Riemanian tensor/Finsler function) from a given global metric $d:M \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Any references about this would be helpful.

A few sources state that the Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{C}P^N$ can be "easily" recovered from the distance function $d(|\psi \rangle, |\phi\rangle) = \arccos(| \langle \psi |\phi \rangle|)$, what is the procedure for this and are these ideas rigorous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer only your last question.

Take a finite-dimensional $\mathbb C$-linear space $V$ equipped with a positive-definite hermitian form $\langle-,-\rangle$. The tangent space $\text{T}_p{\mathbb P}_{\mathbb C}V$ at a $1$-dimensional linear subspace $p\subset V$ is naturally identified with $\text{Lin}_{\mathbb C}(p,V/p)$ which in turn is naturally identified with $\text{Lin}_{\mathbb C}(p,p^\perp)$ with respect to the orthogonal decomposition $V=p\oplus p^\perp$. Using this decomposition, we can assume that
$\text{Lin}_{\mathbb C}(p,p^\perp)\subset\text{Lin}_{\mathbb C}(V,V)$ (extending by zeros). The hermitian form on $\text{Lin}_{\mathbb C}(V,V)$ given by the rule $\langle t_1,t_2\rangle=\text{tr}(t_1\circ t_2^*)$ induces on
${\mathbb P}_{\mathbb C}V$ the famous Fubini-Study hermitian structure. Naturally, the distance can be expressed in terms of the original hermitian form on $V$. The distance in the projective space between the points
$0\ne p_1,p_2\in V$ is given by
$\text{dist}(p_1,p_2)=\text{arccos}\frac{\langle p_1,p_2\rangle\langle p_2,p_1\rangle}{\langle p_1,p_1\rangle\langle p_2,p_2\rangle}$.

A similar approach works for many hyperbolic geometries (including the complex hyperbolic one), elliptic geometries, and many others that come from grassmannians.

**Late extension.** It is not necessary to require the form
$\langle-,-\rangle$ to be positive-definite, and one can also take $p\subset V$ of a fixed dimension, say, $k$, thus dealing with the grassmannian $\text{Gr}_{\mathbb C}(k,V)$. As above, the loci of non-degenerate points get their pseudo-hermitian structure. Many objects of these geometries (such as geodesics, bisectors, etc) admit an easy linear/hermitian description. The degenerate points form the absolute whose geometry can also be described in the hermitian/linear terms. (It is also possible to take $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb H$ (or even simetimes $\mathbb O$) in place of $\mathbb C$.)

Comment: Are these things written down somewhere? The complex projective space pops up often enough as well as the Fubini-Study metric but I would love to see a comprehensive treatment including also other base-fields and Grassmanians.

Comment: @Vít Tuček Yes, you can read it here http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702714 http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4469 http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4470 (For first year students, http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0346 can be easier.)

Answer (score 3):

I think the book on Petrunin's homepage might be of interest to you.

http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/alexandrov/bbi.pdf

The part of the Finsler metric answer your question in the positive.

Comment: More precisely, chapter 2 defines the notion of "Length space" and example 2.2.5 is on the lenght structure of a Finsler geometry.